# Running Word Count in Local cluster in Apache Storm

Tags: maven, apache-storm

I am trying to follow the book

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781449324025?iid=2013-12-blog-storm-book-9781449324025-SBOBlog

to run Storm cluster and create first topology. These are the steps that i followed

1) Installed Maven

2) Installed maven plugin for Eclipse

3) Create new Maven project in Eclipse with artifact name as stormArtifact

4) It generated a folder structure and a pom.xml file

5) i updated that pom.xml as follows.

6) I added spouts and bolts as specified in this link

https://github.com/storm-book/examples-ch02-getting_started/zipball/master

7) Now i am running it using the command

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="TopologyMain" -Dexec.args="src/main/resources/words.txt"
```

But it is throwing an error as follows

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java (def
ault-cli) on project stormArtifact: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.code
haus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParamete
rException
```

**My pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>stormGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>stormArtifact</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
<!-- Repository where we can found the storm dependencies -->
<repository>
<id>clojars.org</id>
<url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
<!-- Storm Dependency -->
<dependency>
<groupId>storm</groupId>
<artifactId>storm</artifactId>
<version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

**ToplogyMain class**

```
import spouts.WordReader;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import bolts.WordCounter;
import bolts.WordNormalizer;


public class TopologyMain {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //Topology definition
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("word-reader",new WordReader());
    builder.setBolt("word-normalizer", new WordNormalizer())
        .shuffleGrouping("word-reader");
    builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounter(),1)
        .fieldsGrouping("word-normalizer", new Fields("word"));

    //Configuration
    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.put("wordsFile", args[0]);
    conf.setDebug(false);
    //Topology run
    conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);
    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology("Getting-Started-Toplogie", conf, builder.createTopology());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    cluster.shutdown();
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try to explicit the maven-exec-plugin in the pom with a profile for instance?

Comment: did you run `mvn clean package` before running the command?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but i first install the [storm binary distribution](https://storm.apache.org/downloads.html) in my local machine and then ran `mvn package` command in my main `pom.xml`.

It worked!

> If you are using the latest development version of Storm, e.g. by
>   having cloned the [**Storm git repository**](https://github.com/apache/storm), then you must first perform a
>   **local build of Storm itself**